# No-bake cheesecake - freeze or chill overnight?

Tags: freezing, cheesecake

Good day, I made a big batch of no bake blueberry cheesecakes for an event tomorrow. My question is, do I put it in the freezer or do I put it in the refrigerator? My concern is that if the temperature is not low enough, the icing I placed around the edges will deform and melt. My mom said that if the temperature is too low, the consistency will be ruined when the cheesecakes get thawed tomorrow.

What do I do? Is it possible to just set the freezer on a slightly higher temp? Setting the fridge to a lower temp isn't an option because I don't have enough space there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your refrigerator should be set at a temperature below 4 Celsius. If it isn't, then you are exposing yourself to danger from eating the other things stored there.

At this temperature, the cheesecake will keep perfectly without the icing deforming. Indeed, it will probably even keep well if the fridge temeprature is slightly high.

Under no circumstances should you increase the temperature of your freezer. The cake risks texture change if it freezes. A freezer should always be kept below freezing, or else the other food stored in there will take large hits to both quality and safety.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As a follow-up, is it possible to achieve the same temperature in an icebox? Will the ice + salt combination cut it?

Comment: @Razgriz you shouldn't keep it in an icebox with salt. This will be too cold (below freezing) and it can make your cheese filling grainy upon thawing.